# Encountering and error: "Wrong input format: sample_serial_number out of range" when trying to use a precomputed kernel with LibSVM

Tags: java, kernel, svm, libsvm

I'm attempting to use a precomputed kernel with LibSVM 3.17 (Java Version) but am encountering an error which states: 'Wrong input format: sample_serial_number out of range' within the read_problem() method in the svm_train class.

I am using a linear kernel to begin with i.e. taking the dot-product of two vectors. The data I'm using has been scaled using svm_scale in the range [-1,1]. When saving my precomputed kernel, I'm saving out the ID of the row (which is effectively a unique identifier for the row) for my first column and the contents of the matrix for subsequent columns. My generated matrix is symmetric and I've included the first couple of entries of the file contents below for your evaluation:

```
1   0:10.3098007199 1:9.691388073999995 2:8.269529587900001 3:10.836359234799996
2   0:9.691388073999995 1:10.441238090599997    2:7.5937360488  3:9.193978496500002
3   0:8.269529587900001 1:7.5937360488  2:8.1263441462  3:9.8885507424
4   0:10.836359234799996    1:9.193978496500002 2:9.8885507424  3:13.705259598099996
```

The error itself occurs when when the value:

```
    48:0.015231278900000159
```

is encountered in my precomputed kernel file (which happens to be on the first line). The error arises because the value above fails the following test:

```
if ((int)prob.x[i][0].value <= 0 || (int)prob.x[i][0].value > max_index)
```

where prob.x[i][0].value = 0.015231278900000159 within read_problem() in svm_train.

I'm a bit stuck as to how to proceed with this. I'm wondering if I have saved the data in the correct file format? I have read the README within LibSVM and I *think* I'm doing everything correctly (but obviously not)!! I've also looked at other answers given already, such as:

[Libsvm precomputed kernels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10978261/libsvm-precomputed-kernels) and
[Precomputed Kernels with LibSVM in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474460/precomputed-kernels-with-libsvm-in-python)

but unfortunately I can't see the answer within them.

One final note: When I scaled the data in the range [0,1], the above error did not happen (as all the values in the matrix where now >= 1) but I'm puzzled as to why a negative value within the matrix seems to be causing problems in the first place.

Any help/insight offered would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem with another careful reading of John Robertson's post at the following:

[Precomputed Kernels with LibSVM in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474460/precomputed-kernels-with-libsvm-in-python?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

I received the same message and the solution turned out to be the range of the parameters specified for the training is not valid. For example, in my case, I was trying to enter '-t 4' while the t flag options are (0,1,2,3) only.